# Como no detectar mayusculas en Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

He hecho un programa en Python 3.5 para preguntarme palabras a mi mismo. Pero tengo un problema:

```
dictionary = {}

numpal = int(input("Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))
if numpal<=0:
    print("El numero de palabras tiene que ser mayor que 0.")
    numpal = int(input("Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: "))

count = 0

for i in range(numpal):
    palabra = str(input("\nEscribe aqui la palabra: "))
    traduccion = str(input("Escribe aqui la traduccion de {0}: ".format(palabra)))
    dictionary[palabra] = traduccion
for palabra, traduccion in dictionary.items():
    print('\nCual es la traduccion de "{0}"?'.format(palabra))
    respuesta = input("\nEscribe aqui la traduccion: ")


    if respuesta == traduccion:
        print("La respuesta es correcta.")
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print("La respuesta es incorrecta.")

nota = float(count / numpal * 9 + 1)
print('Tu nota es un ' + str(nota)+ '.')

if nota < 6:
    print('Uy, necesitas estudiar mas tus palabras .')
elif nota > 8:
    print ('Perfecto! Sabes tus palabras perfectamente.')
else:
    print('Dominas las palabras, pero te recomiendo que estudies un poco mas.')
```

> Output

```
Cuantas palabras quieres que te pregunte?: 2

Escribe aqui la palabra: Gato
Escribe aqui la traduccion de Gato: Cat

Escribe aqui la palabra: Perro
Escribe aqui la traduccion de Perro: Dog

Cual es la traduccion de "Gato"?

Escribe aqui la traduccion: Cat
La respuesta es correcta.

Cual es la traduccion de "Perro"?

Escribe aqui la traduccion: DOG  

#Quiero que esto me lo cuente como respuesta correcta,que de igual si lo escribes con mayusculas o minusculas.

La respuesta es incorrecta.
Tu nota es un 5.5.
Uy, necesitas estudiar mas tus palabras .
```

Cómo puedes ver, si pongo la palabra en mayúsculas o algo que no sea lo que he puesto en la traducción, me da respuesta incorrecta. Cómo puedo solucionar este problema y que reconozca la palabra aunque tenga minúsculas o mayúsculas?

Comment: Ya esta editado

Comment: Vale, ahora quita el enlace y pon las pruebas que hiciste con los outputs que te salen y los que te esperas

Comment: He escrito dentro del output lo que espero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu linea de comparación

```
 if respuesta == traduccion:
```

Pon:

```
respuesta.lower() == traduccion.lower():
```

Para que te las pase todas a minúsculas y compare independientemente de las mayúsculas guardadas y las introducidas.

Si pones `DOG` y la traducción es `Dog` a la hora de comparar será un  `"dog" == "dog"`  lo cual es `True`